# How to evaluate the results in the KITTI odometry dataset

Tags: c++, opendata, slam, kitti

I am trying to use KITTI open dataset to do some tests about vision odometry or vision INS odometry. But I can't understand the codes which are provided by KITTI odometry.

I have downloaded the development kit (I think that it includes some codes in C++) for odometry dataset in the KITTI website. (Visit http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_odometry.php)

It provides the benchmark to evaluate other results compared with the ground truth poses it provided. I have tried to build the codes with `cmake` on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but it seemed to not work.

There are four documents in the development kit folder, which are `matrix.h`, `matrix.cpp`, `evaluate_odometry.cpp` and `mail.h`. I fear some class members may be missing in the `evaluate_odometry.cpp` file. It is shown below:

```
int32_t main (int32_t argc,char *argv[]) {

// we need 2 or 4 arguments!
if (argc!=2 && argc!=4) {
  cout << "Usage: ./eval_odometry result_sha [user_sha email]" << endl;
  return 1;
}

// read arguments
string result_sha = argv[1];

// init notification mail
Mail *mail;
if (argc==4) mail = new Mail(argv[3]);
else         mail = new Mail();
mail->msg("Thank you for participating in our evaluation!");

// run evaluation
bool success = eval(result_sha,mail);
if (argc==4)
  mail->finalize(success,"odometry",result_sha,argv[2]);
else
  mail->finalize(success,"odometry",result_sha);

// send mail and exit
delete mail;
return 0;
}
```

The class member `mail->finalize()` cannot be found in any of the files which the kit provides. However, I searched the question online, but it was usually related to JAVA. I don't think that it is a question with JAVA.

Maybe I am missing something in the kit and I'll check it. Could someone help me? What can I do next?

Update:
I have downloaded the KITTI Odometry development kit from the KITTI website again to make sure that it is complete. However, it still exists the question above.

Comment: You're right, there appears to be code missing. You could always just comment out the offending parts unless you really need it to send an e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

You need add (in mail.h):

```
void finalize (bool success,std::string benchmark,std::string result_sha="",std::string user_sha="")
 {
   if (success)
   {
    msg("Your evaluation results are available at:");
    msg("http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/user_submit_check_login.php?benchmark=%s&user=%s&result=%s",benchmark.c_str(),user_sha.c_str(), result_sha.c_str());
   }
   else
   {
    msg("An error occured while processing your results.");
    msg("Please make sure that the data in your zip archive has the right format!");
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I miss some codes in the mail.h from the odometry development kit tools. I will try it again.